# Iptables prerouting and IP forwarding

Tags: linux, shell, routing, iptables

I have a linux machine used as gateway for a Win XP machine. Both are in Virtual machine for testing purpose. Now I want to trick the Win XP user (me) with the forwarding of an IP address: I want to change the destination IP address.

For example I want to go to 1.1.1.1 but linux gateway change it to 2.2.2.2
So if I'm expecting the web page of 1.1.1.1, I'll get the changed one, the one of 2.2.2.2
For example I want to go to Facebook and I'm forced to Google home page.

How can I do it? With prerouting?
Because I've done lot of tries, but no one working :(

Comment: Obviously this is not a programming question, so voting to close.

Comment: Maybe don't close it but transfer it to serverfault

Comment: Should be on superuser/serverfault. Either way, `-t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.2` should do it. You'll need a POSTROUTING SNAT as well so the response returns through the gateway - if it's a NAT'ing gateway I presume you already have that

Comment: Thanks Erik, I did that way, with that rule of PREROUTING and as POSTROUTING I have: `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`, and tried lot of other configuration. Still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use the etc/hosts (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) in Win XP?
You can add a line like this one : "www.google.com www.facebook.com" in your host file to redirect request to www.facebook.com to www.google.com  (you should also add a line without the www).
You can try the same thing on the linux (I don't think it'll work).

The best would be that your linux serves DNS for you, so you can configure your DNS software for that purpose.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` only maps _names_ to _IP addresses_. You cannot map a name to another name this way.